# Confusing about the scope of the variables in C

Tags: c, struct, scope, global-variables, sizeof

```
Code 1
#include <stdio.h>
int T;
int main()
{
   struct T{ double x;};
   printf("%d", sizeof(T));
   return 0;
}
```

> Output: 4

```
Code 2
#include <stdio.h>
struct T{ double x;};
int main()
{
   int T;
   printf("%d", sizeof(T));
   return 0;
}
```

> Output: 4

For the `code 1`, I think that the output is the size of the global variable(`int T`) that's why it gives 4.

But for the `code 2`, it gives output 4, according to the global variable logic, it should be output 8 for `struct T{ double x;};`.

Here, the global variable concept is not correct - I think.

Can anyone please explain this why the output looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here isn't the scope but how structures tags live in a different *namespace* than other symbols.

Because of this when you do `sizeof(T)` you *always* get the variable `T`.

To get a structure tag in C you need the `struct` keyword. As in `sizeof(struct T)`.

---

Things would be different if you used `typedef`:

```
struct T
{
    double x;
} T;
```

Then you would have a type named `T` in the "normal" namespace. On the other hand that type would conflict with the variable with the same name so you would get a compiler error instead.

Comment: With a typedef for `T`, there wouldn't be a compiler error.  The two names would be in different (nested) scopes; the inner name would be the one used in the `printf()` statement (with the `sizeof` operator).